# The R chol2inv() method gives me strange results

Tags: r, matrix, covariance, matrix-inverse, inverse

So I'm trying to invert a big (449x449) covariance matrix, which is thus symmetric and positive definite.
(What I'm trying to do is to invert this matrix as part of a Gaussian Process fitting for the Mauna Loa CO2 dataset.)

This inversion is pretty long, so I wanted to use chol2inv instead of solve.
But the chol2inv method gives me a very strange result : a matrix very close to 0 (sum of it is equal to 10^(-13)).

Why would chol2inv give me this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you have wrongly used `chol2inv`. It takes **the upper triangular Cholesky factor** rather than the covariance matrix as input. So if `A` is your covariance matrix, you want

```
chol2inv(chol(A))
```

not

```
chol2inv(A)
```

---

Just found out that this issue was answered twice long long ago.

- [Comparing matrix inversions in R - what is wrong with the Cholesky method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26718334/4891738) (in 2014)
- [matrix inversion R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15336123/4891738) (in 2013)